# How to know which version of Symfony I have?

Tags: php, symfony

I know that I have downloaded a `Symfony2` project and started with but I have updated my vendor several times and I want to know which version of symfony I have

Any idea ?

Comment: sonata-project/core-bundle is at version 2.3.9 and sonata-project/admin-bundle is at version 2.3.7, according to the `composer show` command.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Run `app/console --version` (for Symfony3: `bin/console --version`), it should give you a pretty good idea. On a random project of mine, the output is:

```
Symfony version 2.2.0-DEV - app/dev/debug
```

If you can't access the console, try reading `symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php`, where the version is [hardcoded](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L62), for instance:

```
const VERSION         = '2.2.0';
```

Just in case you are wondering, `console` creates an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application`. In this class constructor, it uses `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION` to initialize its parent constructor.

Comment: or just take a look at top left in symfony dev bar ( visible only in dev mod ) !

Comment: Thank you so much, found it `/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php`

Comment: for me it's `bin/console --version`

Comment: @Black that's because that's how you check it in Symfony3. OP's answer is for symfony2

Comment: It's helpful to me to know that console is a php file. So, just typing `app/console ...` etc. at the command line does nothing (for me). But `php app/console --version` successfully runs the file. (Maybe people often have a PHP interpreter set up for their shell's environment?)

Answer (score 45):

Although there are already many good answers I'd like to add an option that hasn't been mentioned. Using the command:

```
php bin/console about
```

you can get many details about the current project. The first section is about Symfony itself and looks like this:

```
-------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
 Symfony                                                         
-------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
 Version              4.2.3                                      
 End of maintenance   07/2019                                    
 End of life          01/2020                                    
-------------------- -------------------------------------------
```

I find the other information besides the version number very useful.

There are also other sections providing details about the (framework) Kernel, PHP,  Environment.

Answer (score 26):

Another way is to look at the source for `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` for where `const VERSION` is defined. Example on [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L62)

Locally this would be located in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php`.

Answer (score 20):

Use the following command in your Terminal/Command Prompt:

```
php bin/console --version
```

This will give you your Symfony Version.

Answer (score 9):

also you can check the version of symfony and versions of all other installed packages by running

```
composer show
```

or

```
composer show | grep sonata
```

to get versions of specific packages like sonata etc.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to dynamicallly display your Symfony 2 version in pages, for example in footer, you can do it this way.

Create a service:

```
<?php

namespace Project\Bundle\DuBundle\Twig;

class SymfonyVersionExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{


 public function getFunctions()
 {
 return array(
 //this is the name of the function you will use in twig
 new \Twig_SimpleFunction('symfony_version', array($this, 'b'))
   );
 }

public function getName()
{
//return 'number_employees';
 return 'symfony_version_extension';
}   

public function b()
{
 $symfony_version = \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION;
 return $symfony_version;
}
}
```

Register in service.yml

```
 dut.twig.symfony_version_extension:
    class: Project\Bundle\DutBundle\Twig\SymfonyVersionExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    #arguments: []
```

And you can call it anywhere. In Controller, wrap it in JSON, or in pages example footer

```
 <p> Built With Symfony {{ symfony_version() }} Version MIT License</p>
```

Now every time you run composer update to update your vendor, symfony version will also automatically update in your template.I know this is overkill but this is how I do it in my projects and it is working.

Answer (score 5):

we can find the symfony version using **Kernel.php** file but problem is the Location of Kernal Will changes from version to version (Better Do File Search in you Project Directory)

in symfony 3.0 : 
my_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php

**Check from Controller/ PHP File**

```
$symfony_version = \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION;
echo $symfony_version; // this will return version; **o/p:3.0.4-DEV**
```

Answer (score 5):

if you trying with version  symfony

please try  with

symfony 2 +

> cmd>php app/console --version

symfony 3+

> cmd>php bin/console --version

for example

> D:project>php bin/console --version

```
Symfony 3.2.8 (kernel: app, env: dev, debug: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 3.4

Check the constant in this file vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php

```
const VERSION = '3.4.3';
```

OR

```
composer show | grep symfony/http-kernel
```

Comment: Both of these approaches still work in February 2023; most of the other answers to the OP's question don't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

From inside your Symfony project, you can get the value in PHP this way:

```
$symfony_version = \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::VERSION;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the anwswers here are obsolete... in any case, for me running Symfony 4, it is easy
Just type `symfony -V` from the command line.

[image]

Comment: This gives the version of the Symfony CLI client and not the Symfony PHP components.

Answer (score 1):

This page is the top Google result for search `which version symfony using`, and the top answers probably don't work anymore.

Apparently I'm on Symfony 5, after running `symfony new aqua_note` (from SymfonyCasts recommendation).

I had to ultimately run `grep -r VERSION . | grep Kernel` to see `./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:    public const VERSION = '5.4.2';`... at least I think that's correct now.

Comment: `bin/console --version` still works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in app_dev, you can find symfony version at the bottom left corner of the page

Comment: You might need to open the debug toolbar by clicking on the Symfony logo in the bottom right corner of your screen ;)