# Symfony .htaccess rewrite and redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I know very little about symfony framework. I copied a website www.example.net to www.example.com site works with url

```
www.example.com/www/app.php
```

or even with

```
www.example.com/www/
```

but I want it to redirect automatically to app.php without showing it in the url. My htaccess in the www (web) directory is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
<IfModule>
```

It doesn't redirect.

Thanks

Comment: cleared your cache after copying? ;)

Comment: Yes I'd cleared the cache.

Comment: shall I put this below RewriteEngine On ?

Comment: yes otherwise the rule would be ignored if rewrite engine was disabled for your vhost and enabled only by the htaccess file. Add `RewriteBase /www`

Comment: Tried this, but no luck.

Comment: which version of symfony? read the comments below the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423983/symfony2-how-to-deploy-in-subdirectory-apache)

Comment: I only know it's Symfony 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846189/how-to-know-which-version-of-symfony-i-have

Comment: It does not matter if it is symfony or not, this is just arewrite issue. Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache? are you using apache? That rewriteBase should have done the trick.

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled? in ubuntu you can enable it like `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In your Vhost:

Change this line (Directory section):

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that rule can you try:

```
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteRule ^((?!app\.php).*)$ app.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Sorry I can't test with Symphony as I am not near my home computer.

Comment: still not redirecting.

Comment: jeah it's the way to make it work if you **want** to run symfony but keep the subdirectory in the url - he just copied my comment :)

Comment: @HarshadManjre: What is DOCUMENT_ROOT value?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this game but I just found an Apache directive that saves so much time and makes your htaccess cleaner. The only caveat is you must have Apache 2.2.16+. To have all urls except valid files (images, etc) use app.php as a front controller use the [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) directive.

```
<Directory "/web/symfony-project">
    FallbackResource /app.php
</Directory>
```