# Symfony2 version switch

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.4

Can I somehow detect inside the code which version of symfony is currently used? 
 I have a bundle which uses a symfony function that has changed in version 2.4 so I need to detect on which version I am running, so that the function which is adequate for the used symfony version will be called

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846189/how-to-know-which-version-of-symfony-i-have) answer should help

Answer (score 2):

The symfony version constant will help you.

You find it in `Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel` - constant `VERSION`.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L62

Comment: will $this->get('kernel')->getBundle(..) work to get the class or what do I have to use, because the Symfony Components are not an actual bundle... or can I use the class loader??

Comment: Hmm.. the kernel class is often loaded by the classloader, because of `$kernel = new HttpKernel($dispatcher, $resolver);`. I would first try `echo $kernel::VERSION` and then `echo Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel::VERSION`.

Comment: htx will check it out tomorrow