# Symfony 4.3 "cache:clear" in prod is crashing servers

Tags: php, caching, symfony4

I have my site under symfony in production, there is a lot of traffic and it works with several servers.

During my maintenance operations, I need to update the cache, but when I do a "cache:clear" the load average increases very high, until the site crashes

```
php bin/console cache:clear
...
...
crash !
```

Comment: I've read about possible problems related to APC https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28430 or php 7.4 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32465. Can you please specify your working environment? (windows, linux, php version, etc)

Comment: In addition to @luigif's comment, use `php bin/console about` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846189/how-to-know-which-version-of-symfony-i-have/54721372#54721372) to get information on your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by migrating cache directory in a non-nfs directory (ex: /tmp/xxx), Now it works !